# for_each not returning (boolean) value

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a program to verify if an IPv4 address entered as string is in valid dotted-quad notation.

The problem I am facing is that I'm not able to return (exit) function once I detect error. As per cppreference documentation for_each returns UnaryFunction. I tried using any_of and all_of but they require me using an loop (range-based loop) inside my lambda function which I'm trying to avoid. Am I missing something or it is not possible to return value in for_each.

```
vector<string> ipExplode;
string ip;
bool    inValidIp = false;
cout << "Server IP : ";
cin >> ip;
trim(ip);
ipExplode = explode(ip, '.');
if(not for_each(ipExplode.begin(), ipExplode.end(), [](const string& str) -> bool{
    int32_t ipNum;
    if(regex_search(str, regex("\\D+")))
        return false;
    try
    {
        ipNum = stoi(str);
        if(ipNum < 0 or ipNum > 255)
            return false;
    }
    catch (std::exception& ex)
    {
        return false;
    }
}))
    return false;
```

Comment: "I tried using any_of and all_of but they require me using an loop (range-based loop) inside my lambda function which I'm trying to avoid" - sorry?

Comment: `all_of` / `any_of` / `none_of` is exactly what you want here, a `UnaryPredicate`.

Comment: _"I tried using any_of and all_of but they require me using an loop (range-based loop) inside my lambda function"_ How so?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

from [`for_each`](http://For%20both%20overloads,%20if%20the%20iterator%20type%20is%20mutable,%20f%20may%20modify%20the%20elements%20of%20the%20range%20through%20the%20dereferenced%20iterator.%20If%20f%20returns%20a%20result,%20the%20result%20is%20ignored.):

> If f returns a result, the result is ignored.

i.e. there is no point in returning a value from your `for_each` lambda.

A good choice here is [`all_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of), which accepts a `UnaryPredicate` rather than a `UnaryFunction`, since you want to make sure that *all of* the parts of the string pass the lambda successfully:

```
bool isValid = std::all_of(ipExplode.begin(), ipExplode.end(), [](const std::string& str) -> bool{
    if(regex_search(str, regex("\\D+")))
        return false;
    try
    {
        int32_t ipNum = stoi(str);
        if(ipNum < 0 or ipNum > 255)
            return false;
    }
    catch (std::exception& ex)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
});
```

`all_of` will stop iterating once an invalid part is found.

Comment: The OP could instead use the RPM instruction to get the code to decide if the OP wants "any of" or "all of" in this case.

Comment: @Yakk What is an RPM instruction?

Comment: It is from an old programming language: http://lists.ding.net/geeks/99/aug/msg00007.html -- unlike WPM, it should be safe to import to C++.

Answer (score 1):

> Am I missing something or it is not possible to return value in for_each.

`for_each` does return the `UnaryFunction`. But if you put a unary function to `if` expression, its meaningless.

In your case, a lambda without capturing can implicitly convert to a function pointer. A non-null function pointer as a boolean value is always `true`. Thus your

```
if(not for_each( /* ... */ ))
```

will be evaluated to `false` all the time.

As commentators and other answerers have already written, `std::all_of` is what you want here.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `for_each` anyway. Replace it by the ranged-based for and it all becomes so much simpler and elegant. Put it all in a function and there you go:

```
auto is_ip_valid(const std::vector<std::string>& ipExplode)
{
    for (auto&& str : ipExplode)
    {
       // ...
    }
}
```